# How to delete rows depending on the previous column - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

i've a table which looks like this:

```
action | timespan
------ | ------
start  |  NULL
------ | ------
finish | 00:10:30
------ | ------
start  | 00:05:00
------ | ------
start  | 00:00:01
------ | ------
abort  | 00:05:20
------ | ------
abort  | 00:12:33
```

the duplicate actions are coming from  the backend , but i still need a accurate as possible timespan
therefore i need to delete every duplicated actions which come after the previous action 
so that every beginning (start) has a end (finish/abort)
something like this

```
action | timespan
------ | ------
start  |  NULL
------ | ------
finish | 00:10:30
------ | ------
start  | 00:05:00
------ | ------
abort  | 00:05:20
------ | ------
```

is this possible in postgresql and if yes how?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [lag](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) function.

For example:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    action,
    lag(action) over () as last_action,
    timespan
  FROM foo
) AS a
WHERE a.last_action IS NULL OR a.action <> a.last_action
```

Comment: it kinda solved realized that the problem was  that the events are overlapping